# Advice on creating a menu (image attached)

Tags: android, layout, menu

Below is an image of GPS Essentials app, which I guess a lot uses.

I am interested in making a menu similar to this. How is such a menu (or what ever it is called) created.

My first thought was to use a ListView having elements containing an image and text-view in vertical orientation. But then I was wondering if there is any better, preferably an easier way to do it.

I would be very greatful if you could share your experience with me. Thank you.

[image: Menu of GPS Essentials app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GridView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) is the solution exactly. You have to actually define a **custom adapter** for the GridView.

Why custom adapter? Because you have to inflate a custom row (having ImageView and TextView) to every item in your GridView.

**Hint:** Search for the example with word "Android Gridview example", you will get many articles/tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

use GridView. You can find documentation here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html